What is the best way to recall data in both iOS and Android?
I am looking for a way to store coordinates in storage to move labels around my container. I could take screen shots and replay them with imageviewer, but I am concerned with the size of storage if I had hundreds of screen shots saved after months of app use.
Has anyone had success with similar coding? In Java I would use text files and read from there, but I saw Shai's comment that iOS does not like text files, and most of my users will have iPads. I could do it in SQL, but it seams there could also be issues with that approach.
Thanks for being a giving community. I have learned so much from everyone's comments.

When did I mention iOS doesn't like text files? I don't recall such an assertion. You can use Storage and just write in JSON representing your UI hierarchy. Notice you should be careful when serializing the UI since getClass() will return obfuscated class names so relying on its behavior would be problematic.
